# What would be a formal substitute for the informal quantifiers "a lot of" and "lots of"?

Tags: formality, quantifiers

***A lot of, lots of with a noun***

We use a lot of and lots of in informal styles. Lots of is more informal than a lot of. A lot of and lots of can both be used with plural countable nouns and with singular uncountable nouns for affirmatives, negatives, and questions:

- We’ve got lots of things to do.
- That’s a lot of money.
- There weren’t a lot of choices.

[source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers)

---

Can we use the quantifiers in formal writings, and is there any substitute for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they can be used in formal writing. *More* formal-seeming alternatives include "a great deal":

> We've **a great deal** to do.
>   That's **a great deal** of money.

"Many" is less formal than that, but more than "a lot":

> We've **many** things to do.

But it can only be used with countable nouns. Don't use:

> That's **many** money.

Then there's are some versions that are formal, but only work in some cases:

> There wasn't **a wide range** of choices.

("Wide range" is singular, so *weren't* needs to become *wasn't*)

Other alternatives can be excessively complex/unusual, although they will be understood.

> There wasn't **a considerable quantity** of choices.
>   That's **a considerable quantity** of money.

Answer (score 0):

**MANY**
ADJECTIVE, PRONOUN, & DETERMINER
A large number of.

**as determiner** ‘many people agreed with her’
**as pronoun** ‘the solution to many of our problems’
‘many think bungee jumping is a new craze’
**as adjective** ‘one of my many errors’

Many is a more formal phrasing than "lots of".